# How do I round a number in SQLAlchemy and MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

What is the SQLAlchemy equivalent of MySQL's `ROUND(n,x)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLAlchemy allows producing (almost) any SQL function expression using the [`func`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/functions.html) utility:

```
func.round(n, x)
```